# SQLalchemy query get aggregate array of dicts

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to get an aggregate array containing dictionaries from an SQLAlchemy query? e.g.

```
session.query(
    Object.name,
    func.array_agg({Location.id: Location.name}).label('locations')
)\
    .join(Location)\
    .all()
```

So the expected result will be:

```
[
 ('Horizontal neutral circuit',
  [{143:'A5'},{145:'A8'},{765:'B12'}]),
 ('Fletcher, Lopez and Edwards',
  [{41:'A1'},{76:'B8'},{765:'B12'}]),
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you could use [`json_build_object()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) to build your dictionaries:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

session.query(
        Object.name,
        postgresql.array_agg(
            func.json_build_object(Location.id,
                                   Location.name)).label('locations'))\
    .join(Location)\
    .group_by(Object.name)\
    .all()
```

with the caveat that the keys will be strings, compared to your example's integer keys.